# Google authentication Xamarin invalid redirect uri

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-authentication

I need to make authentication using Google for my app (Xamarin Android Native). I used this [article](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/). I passed step by step. Also I created client id in Google Developer Console. But I have an error. The package name is displayed on the screenshot. What can be wrong with this?[image]

```
public const string RedirectUrl = "com.xplorpal.pal_:/oauth2redirect";
_auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId, string.Empty, scope,
                                        new Uri(AuthorizeUrl),
                                        new Uri(redirectUrl),
                                        new Uri(AccessTokenUrl),
                                        null, IsUsingNativeUI);
```

Comment: I'm sure someone could help you with this, but your question needs to use the proper coding mark-up. It's recommended strongly that you don't use screenshots of code.

Comment: What value is in redirectUrl? com.xplotal.pal_: does seem like an invalid URL.

Comment: @Nick, yes, but according to that article the author uses this redirectUri `public const string RedirectUrl = "com.woodenmoose.xamarin.googleauth:/oauth2redirect";` It must be a package name with `:/oauth2redirect`

Comment: It looks like that article is split into 2 parts. The first part is for the PCL and the second part is for the Xamarin. I'm assuming that the Configuration.Redirect that is in the Xamarin part is for that GoogleAuthenticator not the OAuth2Authenticator. I could be wrong though just my guess based on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the underscore in the redirect URL:

```
public const string RedirectUrl = "com.xplorpal.pal:/oauth2redirect";
_auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId, string.Empty, scope,
                                        new Uri(AuthorizeUrl),
                                        new Uri(redirectUrl),
                                        new Uri(AccessTokenUrl),
                                        null, IsUsingNativeUI);
```

Here you can find more info about why the UriFormatException is thrown. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/z6c2z492(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, I tried both variants. Also I changed package name in Google Dev Console and in the project manifest

Comment: Have you tried using new Uri (string.Format ("{0}","com.xplorpal.pal:/oauth2redirect")) ?

Comment: I dont know why but the problem disappeared when I changed the package name everywhere (in Google Dev Console and in project manifest and redirect uri). So now it is `public const string RedirectUrl = "com.xplorpaltravel.pal:/oauth2redirect";` and it works. I dont know why. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: I added to the answer the explanation for the possible reasons for the exception.